# Where is the login guest account?

Tags: macos, guest-account

I have a guest staying in my apartment and I would like her to use my iMac as guest. But when she boots it, she sees only the login to my account and cannot find any reference to the guest account.  How does she find the login to the guest account?

(iMac late 2015 OS updated recently)

Answer (score 5):

To set this up you need to activate it.

1. Go to Apple menu > System Preferences
2. Select Users & Groups
3. Click the lock icon to unlock it
4. Enter an administrator name and password
5. Select Guest User in the list of users.
6. Select “Allow guests to log in to this computer.”
7. Click the lock icon to lock it
8. Close the window

Hope this helps.

Comment: In addition you could add about Parental Controls if required so that the account is misused.